# Why inserting lines of code with File class declaration is not inserted into top of my file?

Tags: phpstorm

In my PhpStorm 2021.1.4, when I paste some lines of code, like :

```php
if (File::exists($mediaImage->getPath())) {
```

class declaration

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
```

is not inserted into my file.

But for some lines of code relative classes are added automatically.

Which settings have I to look at ?

Comment: 1) What classes are added automatically? Please show a few examples. 2) How are you fixing it? Manually adding the whole `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;` line? Or by using some quick fix menu offered by the IDE? If menu/fix from IDE -- what  do you see then? What options does it gives to you?

Comment: Right now it looks like there are more than 1 class named `File` in your project and PhpStorm cannot guess for you what the right class might be (even though it may still offer `Illuminate\Support\Facades\File` as #1 in the quick fix list).